# upload json file and read it in angualr 8

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular8

Below is my code but I am getting undefined :

```
onChange(fileList: FileList): void {
    var file = fileList[0];
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    var newFile = {};
    fileReader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
    fileReader.onload = () => {
      newFile = fileReader.result as object;
      this.updateObj = cloneDeep(newFile);
    };
    console.log('updateObj', this.updateObj);
}
```

I want to upload json file (ARM template)and read it but in console.log this.updateObj is showing undefined.

Comment: `this.updateObj` is assigned in the onload function call. You are console.logging the value before it is assigned. Move the `console.log` statement inside the onload function call as well

Comment: @peinearydevelopment yes I know but how i can access value out side onload function . I want to access that fileReader.result outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very unclear as to what you are asking. I think this should answer your question though.

In the future, creating an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will make it much easier for others to help you.

`.ts`

```
  updateObj: any;
  onChange(event: any): void {
    var file = event.target.files[0];
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
    fileReader.onload = () => {
      const newFile = fileReader.result as string;
      this.updateObj = JSON.parse(newFile);
    };
  }
```

`.html`

```
<input type="file" (change)="onChange($event)" />

<pre><code>{{updateObj | json}}</code></pre>
```

Stackblitz is a wonderful tool to user for creating MRE's for an Angular question.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xdjvwh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**UPDATE**

@DnyaneshSurya Thank you for the MRE. Your example is working, but it still isn't clear what you want to do. `ngOnInit` is only called once when the component is initialized. The value for your `Input` at that time is undefined. That won't change as the `ngOnInit` method is only called once. Your variable `armTemplate` is getting updated though, as can be seen if you would update your hello component template to be `<h1>{{armTemplate | json}}</h1>`. If you want to perform some action when that value gets updated though, then the easiest way would be to use the getter/setter on your `armTemplate` property.

Here is another [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mxjqgx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts) example to demonstrate.

Comment: thanks for the reply I agree with you I already done this . I want to pass updateObj value as parent to child component using @Input property my Parent component is    .html <div class="col-12">
          <input type="file" (change)="onChange($event.target.files)">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h2 class="Productscreen_title1">Create Public Address</h2>
        <app-azure-support-dynamic-form-ui [armTemplate]="updateObj">
        </app-azure-support-dynamic-form-ui>     
 </div>   in my child component I am trying to read that json

Comment: @DnyaneshSurya It is very unclear what your question is. Please create an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on Stackblitz demonstrating what you are trying to do and where you are having issues.

Comment: I have  created an MRE on Stackblitz  <a href="https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-akdpot?file=src/app/hello.component.ts> Stackblitz My Example </a>

Comment: @DnyaneshSurya Thank you for the MRE. I have updated my answer to address your updated question/MRE.

Comment: @ peinearydevelopment thank you for the reply but one issue i am getting  if you open console log from hello component its showing setter: hello undefined and init:  undefined. can you please look once again your code.

Comment: @DnyaneshSurya update the parent component to `<hello *ngIf="updatedObj"`

Comment: @ peinearydevelopment  work like a charm !! thank you so much .